# Are there any known focusing issues for the Nikon 70-200 2.8 VR and if so, how to compensate for them?

Tags: nikon, autofocus, image-stabilization

I have recently rented this lens for my D610. I feel that it is just off when auto-focusing? Takes kind of long to focus and does not always seem to focus on the subject I am trying to get in focus.

Is this me or is there a known issue that I could be unaware of?

Comment: Under what conditions are you trying to focus? In what lighting and at what apertures? Is the subject moving?

Comment: Is the lens the VR or VR II?

Comment: It is VR. It actually ended up working no problems so I am guessing the lighting was just a little too dark.

Comment: (-1 until added info) you need to post picture that you think is "not in focus" for people to judge. Also post settings (shutter, aperture, focal length, iso, VR on/off, tri/monopod)

Answer (score 1):

> It actually ended up working no problems so I am guessing the lighting was just a little too dark.

Based upon information from the OP's comment on the question, it sounds like the initial attempt to use the lens was in light that was a bit too marginal for the camera/lens combination to autofocus properly.